# Populate a column created by ADOX with a list C#

Tags: c#, list, ms-access, adox

I created a table in my database with ADOX. I wish to populate my columns with a list. How can I do this? One list is a string which should populate "ScheduleName" column and one list is an integer list which should populate "SchedulePace" column. Here is how I am creating my table:

```
public partial class ScheduleStart : Form
{
    const string _ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=F:\A2 Computing\C# Programming Project\TriHard.accdb";

    private Catalog OpenDatabase()
    {
        Catalog catalog = new Catalog();
        Connection connection = new Connection();

        try
        {
            connection.Open( _ConnectionString);
            catalog.ActiveConnection = connection;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            catalog.Create(_ConnectionString);
        }
        return catalog;
    }


    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Only for demonstration purposes, no error checks:
        // This code will only work as long as the table "Publisher" does not exist

        // First create an new database if necessary
        Catalog cat = OpenDatabase();

        // Create a new table "Publisher" using ADOX
        Table table = new Table();
        table.Name = "ScheduleEvent";
        cat.Tables.Append(table);

        // Add Column "ScheduleID" with Autoincrement
        ADOX.Column col = new Column();
        col.Name = "ScheduleID";
        col.ParentCatalog = cat;
        col.Type = ADOX.DataTypeEnum.adInteger;
        col.Properties["Nullable"].Value = false;
        col.Properties["AutoIncrement"].Value = true;
        table.Columns.Append(col);

        // Add column "ScheduleName"
        col = new Column();
        col.Name = "ScheduleName";
        col.ParentCatalog = cat;
        col.Type = ADOX.DataTypeEnum.adWChar;
        col.DefinedSize = 50;
        col.Attributes = ColumnAttributesEnum.adColNullable;
        table.Columns.Append(col);

        // Add column "SchedulePace"
        col = new Column();
        col.Name = "SchedulePace";
        col.ParentCatalog = cat;
        col.Type = ADOX.DataTypeEnum.adInteger;
        col.DefinedSize = 50;
        col.Attributes = ColumnAttributesEnum.adColNullable;
        table.Columns.Append(col);

        // Make "PublisherID" the primary key
        ADOX.Index index = new ADOX.Index();
        index.PrimaryKey = true;
        index.Name = "PK_ScheduleEvent";
        index.Columns.Append("ScheduleID", table.Columns["ScheduleID"].Type, table.Columns["ScheduleID"].DefinedSize);
        table.Indexes.Append(index);

        MessageBox.Show("The Schedule table has been created");

    }

    public ScheduleStart()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
```

So this creates the table and the primary key increments itself when I add new values. I wish to populate the other two fields with lists I have created. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Once your table has been created you can use either `System.Data.OleDb` or `System.Data.Odbc` to open a `.Connection`, then use a prepared statement (parameterized query) to

```sql
INSERT INTO ScheduleEvent (ScheduleName, SchedulePace) VALUES (?, ?)
```

There are *lots* of examples here on Stack Overflow so you shouldn't have any trouble finding one.